# Laravel maatwebsite excel import and show imported excel in HTML table form?

Tags: laravel, import

I am using maatwebsite for importing excel file in laravel. Sheet is uploaded fine but I didn't get how to show content of excel sheet in laravel view with heading that is the first row. I any one can help me out here. Thanks

Comment: We can't write for you the code. We are here to help you with some issues.

Comment: https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php+read+excel Google can be a friend sometimes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load the excel sheet and convert values to an array:

```
$data = Excel::load('file.xls')->toArray();
```

Convert the keys from the first entry to an array (i.e. the headers):

```
$headers = array_keys($data[0]);
```

Then construct a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        @foreach($headers as $h)
            <th>{{$h}}</th>
        @endforeach
    </tr>

    @foreach($data as $d)
        <tr>
            @foreach($d as $v)
                <td>{{$v}}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

Keep in mind this has no error checking, you should provide some.